# Upgrade Jenkins remotely

Tags: macos, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I need to upgrade a version of Jenkins on a remote machine. The machine (a Mac mini) is running on a LAN but no one is able to locate the actual computer and no one has access to the password (I only have the IP address and Mac username). Is it possible to upgrade the current version of Jenkins on the machine remotely through the Jenkins web interface?

Answer (score 1):

There is a link from within Jenkins

[image]

which is detailed here

http://jenkins-le-guide-complet.batmat.cloudbees.net/html/sect-installation-upgrading.html

I would suggest you find the machine as it could go down if you lose power and also it might need upgrades